# illegal callback type invocation from native module. This callback type only permits a single invocation from native code

Tags: sqlite, react-native, ubuntu-16.04

I developpe a react native application using sqlite.

```
var sqlite = require('react-native-android-sqlite')


var databaseName = 'react.db'
//initialiser base de donnée
 sqlite.init(databaseName)
     .then((_) => {
         console.log('database initialized.')
     }
 )
//declarer une requette
var sql = 'INSERT INTO principale(id, nom) VALUES (1, bonjour)'
 var params = ["Create react native android sqlite", 1]
//fermer la base de donnée

export default class sql2 extends Component {
  //function
  insert() {

sqlite.query(sql, params)
 .then((data) => {
     console.log('retrieved: ', data)
 }
)
     }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <Button title='salut' onPress={this.insert}>Cliquz sur moi</Button>


      </View>
    );
  }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('sql2', () => sql2);
```

I have this error :
illegal callback type invocation from native module. This callback type only permits a single invocation from native code

Comment: that module is outdated...better to use this one https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage

Comment: Please with which version of node.js and react-native ?

Comment: latest versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The react-native-android-sqlite is outdated.
Use sqlite-storage : https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage But it is butter to use : https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#getting-started